# Outbound mail queue lifetime standard

Tags: email, postfix, email-server

**Description:**

I am trying to setup an email server with qmail and postfix as a MTAs.

I am using postfix to handle my outbound mail flow traffic.

**Problem:**

I have set postfix `maximal_queue_lifetime` to 2d. If some mail gets rejected temporarily then postfix holds it for 2 days then generates bounce back.

So users get an NDR (Bounce back) after 2 days.

**What I want:**

Can anybody tell me whether there is any standard to set queue lifetime in MTAs?

Comment: It can certainly be done in sendmail, but I don't know postfix.  I'm sure it can, by analogy, but I'm hoping some else knows how.

Comment: Your "problem" description doesn't describe a problem.  And "What I want" doesn't really tell me what you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to get standard in your MTA, then you can read all links [in the RFCs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#Related_Requests_For_Comments). As postfix built upon this standard, then **default value** in postfix configuration should be standard.

In your case, `maximal_queue_lifetime` [default value is 5d (5 days)](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#maximal_queue_lifetime), you can check it yourself via run

```
postconf -d maximal_queue_lifetime
```

Above configuration derived from [RFC 5231 section 4.5.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.4).

> Retries continue until the message is transmitted or the sender gives
> up; the give-up time generally needs to be at least 4-5 days.  It MAY
> be appropriate to set a shorter maximum number of retries for non-
> delivery notifications and equivalent error messages than for
> standard messages.  The parameters to the retry algorithm MUST be
> configurable.